# How to diplay a popup window when changing the selected value in a dropdown list?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, popupwindow

I want to display a popup window when I select a specific value from drop-down list. But I don't have any idea to do it as I want. I little example would be enough for this. For the pop up I expect to use panel.

Comment: You can do that with jquery. what you've tried? show your code!

Comment: I've tried some codes found in the internet but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple.Use `SelectedIndexChanged` event of dropdownlist

> .aspx

```
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" runat="server" Enabled="false" PopupControlID="PanelMonthly" TargetControlID="ddlfeegroup">
```

> .cs

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ModalPopupExtender2.Enabled = true;
    ModalPopupExtender2.Show();//popup show
}
```

on close button event again make ModalPopupExtender2.Enabled = false; or onclienclick of close button disable it

You can find more information [here](http://www.webcodeexpert.com/2013/04/how-to-open-pop-up-window-on-drop-down.html)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidForModel" runat="server" />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <!-- ModalPopupExtender -->
    <cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="mp1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="hidForModel"
        CancelControlID="btnClose" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">
    </cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" align="center" Style="display: none">
        <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" />
    </asp:Panel>
    <!-- ModalPopupExtender -->
```

**.cs code**

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mp1.Show();
        }
```

**css**

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .modalBackground {
        background-color: Black;
        filter: alpha(opacity=90);
        opacity: 0.8;
    }

    .modalPopup {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        border-width: 3px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: black;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        width: 300px;
        height: 140px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i get an error saying "Error 2 The name 'mp1' does not exist in the current context Default.aspx.cs 53 13 test
". Can you hlp me to resolve this?

Comment: <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>  add this line to your .aspx file and also add "AjaxControlToolkit" package to your project